# Complex numbers subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

Consider the complex numbers

$C = \{a + bi| a, b ∈ R\}$
where $i =\sqrt{−1}$ satisfies $i^2 = −1$. It is a fact (but you need not prove) that the nonzero
complex numbers $C^∗$
form a group under the multiplication operation defined
by
$(a + bi)(c + di) = (ac − bd) + (ad + bc)i$.
Determine the elements of < i >, the subgroup generated by the element $i ∈ C^∗$.

My professor said:

The subgroup $<i>= \{1, i, −1, −i\}$

since

$i^2 = −1$

$i^3 = −i$

and

$i^4 = 1$

My question is does order matter in the way the elements are arranged in the subgroup. So for example, since the subgroup $<i>= \{1, i, −1, −i\}$ Would it have matter if I wrote: 
$<i>= \{i, −1, −i, 1\}$ instead. I'm trying to find out why my teacher started with 1 but not i.

Comment: He’s writing the powers of $i$ in order: $i^0$, $i^1$, $i^2$, $i^3$. But it doesn’t matter.

Comment: A subgroup (apart from anything else it may be) is a **set**.  The order of elements in a set is unimportant.